# Getting wrong date when converting string with timezone

Tags: swift, date

In Swift Playground, I run this.

```
let string = "2019-01-14T00:00:00+08:00"
let utcTimezone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "UTC")!
let sgtTimezone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "SGT")!

let dfs = DateFormatter()
dfs.timeZone = sgtTimezone
dfs.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_sg")
dfs.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ"
dfs.calendar = Calendar(identifier: Calendar.Identifier.iso8601)

let date = dfs.date(from: string)!
```

Why is date = `Jan 13, 2019 at 11:00 PM`  and not the accurate Jan 14, 2019 at 00:00 AM ?

Tried changing the timezone to UTC but by default the result is UTC
I am expecting `Jan 14, 2019 at 00:00 AM`.. or at least Jan 14

Comment: You need to check your time string timezone first. If its "UTC" then you need to convert in the current timezone. but if it's already in current timezone then no need to convert it. You can directly perform conversation of string to date.

Comment: you are showing `Jan 13, 2019 at 11:00 PM` but in what timezone?

Comment: Just to be clear what you see in the console is probably in your timezone.  A Date object by itself does not tell you WHERE something happened, it has no timezone stored it just is a time interval since epoch. I.E, nothing is wrong with your date. Also, the +08:00 in your iso date string does not mean your date will always print in SGT, it only means that you are parsing your date string from a human readable format to a Date (which is basically a glorified timestamp) using that timestamp...after that the timezone is lost.

Comment: @Kubee if you read my code, Jan 13 is dateformatter from sgtTimezone. The string clearly says +08:00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// This lets us parse a date from the server using the RFC3339 format
let rfc3339DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
rfc3339DateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
rfc3339DateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"
rfc3339DateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)

// This string is just a human readable format. 
// The timezone at the end of this string does not mean your date 
// will magically contain this timezone. 
// It just tells the parser what timezone to use to convert this 
// string into a date which is basically just seconds since epoch.
let string = "2019-01-14T00:00:00+08:00"

// At this point the date object has no timezone
let shiftDate = rfc3339DateFormatter.date(from: string)!

// If you want to keep printing in SGT, you have to give the formatter an SGT timezone.
let printFormatter = DateFormatter()
printFormatter.dateStyle = .none
printFormatter.timeStyle = .full
printFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "SGT")!
let formattedDate = printFormatter.string(from: shiftDate)
```

You will notice that it prints 12am.  There is nothing wrong with your code. You just misunderstand the Date object. Most people do.

Edit: I used the RFC formatter found in the Apple docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter).  The result is the same if you use your formatter. And yes, as rmatty said, there are a few things wrong with your formatter (I stand corrected :))

Comment: There's several things wrong with the OP's code (which you fix in this answer). But yes, the primary issue is the misunderstanding of the output of viewing a `Date` instance.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying about the Date object. Indeed it's always in UTC. No `Date` object conversion needed however I ended up looking at the way I display it using timezone. Locale doesn't work somehow